# Calculate total hour of worker based on selected date range

Tags: php, android, sql, android-studio

Database of OTHOUR:

[image]

Hello, i would want to ask how to calculate total sum of hour, type5, type1, type2, type3, as show in picture for each worker id based on selected date range?

For example, i want to calculate total hour of worker from 2020-06-08 to 2020-06-21 which in the result,

```
workerid    hour      type5     type1     type2     type3
04405     00:00:00  00:00:00  00:00:00   00:00:00  00:00:00
04408     12:00:00  02:00:00  00:00:00   08:00:00  02:00:00
04458     12:30:00  00:00:00  08:00:00   04:30:00  00:00:00
```

which 04408 have 2 day in date range, so it will sum the hour while 04405 didnt have any ot in date range, so it return 00:00:00

how would i do in sql or php, now i creating an android app, thank you

Updated---

```
 <?php
include_once("dbconnect.php");

$sql ="with tempTable as (
select 
t.workerid,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.hour)) hour,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.Type5)) Type5,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.Type1)) Type1,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.Type2)) Type2,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.Type3)) Type3
from othour t
group by t.workerid
    ) 
select 
t.workerid,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.hour,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as hour,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.Type5,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as Type5,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.Type1,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as Type1,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.Type2,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as Type2,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.Type3,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as Type3
from tempTable t";

$result= $conn -> query($sql);

if($result -> num_rows > 0) {
    $response["ot"] = array();
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $ot = array();
        $ot[workerid] = $row["workerid"];
        $ot[othour] = $row["hour"];
        $ot[type5] = $row["Type5"];
        $ot[type1] = $row["Type1"];
        $ot[type2] = $row["Type2"];
        $ot[type3] = $row["Type3"];
        array_push($response["ot"], $ot);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo json_encode("error");
}

$conn ->close();

?>
```

Comment: Dataabse were screenshoted on the above picture which tag database of OTHOUR

Comment: sorry for may mislead u, but i want to know calculate total hour based on selected date range, not add all of them, the result still need to match workerid, only hour,type5,type1,type2 and type3 that match to same workerid in selected range will sum together

Answer (score 0):

```
with tempTable as (
select 
t.workerid,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.hour)) hour,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.type5)) type5,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.type1)) type1,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.type2)) type2,
sum(DATEDIFF(minute,0,t.type3)) type3
from YourTable t
/*Where Conditions*/
group by t.workerid
    )
    
select 
t.workerid,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.hour,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as hour,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.type5,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as type5,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.type1,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as type1,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.type2,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as type2,
format(DATEADD(minute,t.type3,0),'HH:mm:ss')  as type3
from tempTable t
```

[image: result]

Comment: but i cannot show in json,maybe my php problem, could u help?

Comment: thanks, but i can't add to json, it show error, maybe my php problem, could u help?

Comment: Hi, I honestly don't know about PHP, but that's for sure the query is correct
So, What is the problem or error?

Comment: i cannot add  the data into json through php, but during key in the code in phpmyadmin, the have error on near with (error with unrecognized statement type near with)